# Configuring PC to Wake on LAN

Tags: windows-7-x64, lan, bios, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to configure my Windows 7 PC to wake on lan (S4 and S5), but it just doesn't work. I have followed all the steps.

1. Changed my network adapter settings to wake on magic packet
2. Opened UDP port 7 on my windows firewall
3. Port forwarded my router on UDP port 7 to my PC
4. Configured BIOS (my motherboard - Intel DH67BL) to wake on LAN

I'm sending the magic packet through an android app (name: wake on lan). I used a sniffer utility on my PC to check if it was receiving the magic packet. Below is the packet details. I have a doubt here, the packet details show MAC address (as below). But, my adapter's MAC address is different. And I have set the correct MAC address while sending the magic packet. Is the app changing the MAC address before sending? Please help!

```
    ---------------------------Wake-On-LAN Magic Packet---------------------------

Time received:
     09/15/12    12:13:34
UDP Header:
    |-Source IP :   157.56.106.184
    |-Destination IP    :   192.168.1.2
    |-Source Port   :   3544
    |-Destination Port  :   52146
    |-UDP Length    :   117
    |-UDP Checksum  :   675
MAC Address:
     FF FF 00 00 00 00
Raw Data (109 bytes):
     00 01 00 00 8C 37 59 92 1E 68 49 48 00 00 00 34
     4D 8A 27 66 D1 60 00 00 00 00 30 3A FF FE 80 00
     00 00 00 00 00 80 00 F2 27 62 C7 95 47 FE 80 00
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FE 86 00 64
     9D 00 00 00 00 00 00 3A 98 00 00 07 D0 03 04 40
     40 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 20 01 00
     00 9D 38 6A B8 FF 00 00 00 00 20 01 00
```

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm voting as off topic for this particular stackexchange site. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 3) Port forwarded my router on UDP port 7 to my PC

You need to forward UPD 7 and/or UDP 9 to LAN broadcast address, not to your PC's IP address.

The reason why is because when your PC is turned off, it doesn't have an IP address assigned, so the router does not have the binding with MAC address <=> IP adress in the ARP table, and can't forward the packet.

Answer (score -1):

Reason: Because you don't Bind Your MAC to Your Local IP

Solution: Access to your router, use MAC Bing (or similar feature)

Note: if you use 2 or more router before your PC, you have to Mac binding and and Port forwarding on ALL router